# FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory (on local dev computer)

Tags: meteor

I'm having this following error while developing on my local computer/machine (Windows 10):

```
FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

This does not happen on my DigitalOcean server. I have no problems with my app on it, but on my development PC, I keep having this error non-stop. I can't develop my app without disruption.

I tried the following things:

1) Deleted my Temp folder on my computer. I had over 3 million files that took me an entire day to clean up.

2) I increased my virtual memory on my computer from 2GB to 3GB (I have an 8GB RAM on my PC)

I looked through StackOverflow for similar questions, but none of the things worked for me. I do have a pretty large app with around 8 dependencies/packages, but I don't understand why all of a sudden it would just slow down and "short circuit" so frequently. The project itself takes a good 5 minutes to load after typing the `meteor` command in the Windows command prompt.

Anyone know how to fix this problem? I have the sense it's because of a Node problem, but not sure how to begin fixing it with Meteor on top of it all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a string to `console.log()` it may contain too much data. Remove the call to `console.log()` and see if it works. It worked in my case. Pass a substring of the string or `string.length` if you just want to confirm that the string contains data.

Comment: I actually fixed it. It was a problem with my Avast Internet Security software. I had to disable most of the live protection and magically, everything went back to normal. It was eating too much memory and slowing everything down, especially my Meteor app.

Comment: @MabehAl-ZuqYadeek you should post the correct answer by itself